# Attempting to batch delete relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to batch delete a particular relationships. However, I am getting a server disconnect error. Does anyone know how to handle this?

MATCH (:Post)-[r:FIRST_POST]->(:Thread)
DETACH DELETE r

I expect all the FIRST_POST relationships to be deleted.

Comment: Show the error.

Comment: The error I am getting is: `Connection to server lost. Reconnecting...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you might have a lot of FIRST_POST you might consider

```
call apoc.periodic.iterate('MATCH (:Post)-[r:FIRST_POST]->(:Thread) return x',' detach delete x',{batchSize:100,iterateList:true})
```